# firebase deploy error in firebase cloud messaging

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I integrate the chat application. when I log in I add fcm token in the firebase database and when sender and receiver chat I got chat notification on both sides.so I did below step

1. install node.js
2. I use node version (v13.11.0) and npm version (6.13.7)
3. then I use npm install -g firebase-tools (firebase-tools@7.16.1 updated 1 package in 18.481s)
4. firebase login (Already logged in as)
5. create a folder and add path then execute firebase init cmd after select function then add my project, select language, install npm ( Firebase initialization complete!)
6. I add below code in index.js

```
    'use strict'
    const functions = require('firebase-functions');
    const admin = require('firebase-admin');
    admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
    exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/Notifications/{receiver_id}/{notification_id}')
    .onWrite((data, context) =>
    {
        const receiver_user_id = context.params.receiver_user_id;
        const notification_id = context.params.notification_id;
        console.log('We have a notification to send to :' , receiver_user_id);
        if (!data.after.val()) 
        {
            console.log('A notification has been deleted :' , notification_id);
            return null;
        }
        const DeviceToken = admin.database().ref(`/Users/${receiver_user_id}/device_token`).once('value');
        return DeviceToken.then(result => 
        {
            const token_id = result.val();
            const payload = 
            {
                notification:
                {
                    title: "New Chat Request",
                    body: `you have a new Chat Request, Please Check.`,
                    icon: "default"
                }
            };
            return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload)
            .then(response => 
                {
                    console.log('This was a notification feature.');
                });
        });
    });
```

7. execute Firebase deploy command I got below error

```
=== Deploying to 'notification-ad12a8'...

i  deploying functions
i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
+  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...

**Error: An unexpected error has occurred.**
```

I tried 3 -4 times but not got any solution.please check code please help me..thank you

Comment: If your deployments are failing, and the CLI isn't giving you a helpful error message, you should contact Firebase support directly for assistance.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: Have you tried checking the logs? What do they say?